# Could we have a "You recently worked at" section in the right side bar?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Could we have a "You recently worked at" section in the right side bar, along to the "Linked", "Related" or "Hot Network Questions" sections?! It should feature a list of links to questions that I have either recently asked, answered, or commented on, potentially across networks. Icons indicating the kind of my involvement would be nice. Length of 10 - 15 should be sufficient.

Comment: What would be the usecase for this? You could just go to your [network profile sorted by "activity"](https://stackexchange.com/users/43574/thomash?tab=activity) and get that information already.

Comment: @Secespitus Ah, yes, I wasn't aware that I have a "network profile", always looked at my SO profile. Still, having this list, condensed and without the awards, in the side bar would be a huge help for me to re-create context when I enter the site. Otherwise, it would be always 3 clicks away (which I consider a lot), and what's more, I'd lose the context of the current page.